# Как связаны BluetoothDevice и состояние BT-адаптора (вкл. / выкл.)?

Tags: android, java, bluetooth

Есть кусок кода:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        discoveredDevices = new HashSet<BluetoothDevice>();
    } else {
        discoveredDevices = (HashSet<BluetoothDevice>) savedInstanceState
                .getSerializable("devices");
        for (BluetoothDevice device : discoveredDevices) {
            adapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
        }
    }
}
```

И код сохранения состояния:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable("devices", discoveredDevices);
}
```

Если отключить БТ и повернуть экран, т.е. попасть в обработчик onActivityCreated, то программа вылетает из-за строки

```
discoveredDevices = (HashSet<BluetoothDevice>) savedInstanceState
                .getSerializable("devices");
```

При этом, если БТ не выключать, то поворачивать можно бесконечно - все работает.
Помогите понять, почему так происходит?

Comment: А полный текст ошибки вы не приведете?

Comment: Простите, а откуда можно этот текст взять? В эмуляторе у меня почему-то поддержки БТ нет...

Comment: Так есть же отладчик DDMS. В связке с eclipse вообще творит чудеса.

Comment: Например мой ответ [здесь](http://hashcode.ru/questions/19430/как-отлаживать-написанное-приложение-средствами-android-sdk)

Comment: Так... Штука несложная. Однако есть сложность с планшетом. Я пользуюсь Samsung Galaxy Tab, а работаю под Убунтой. А сложность в том, что планшет определяется, как МТР-устройство и монтироваться не хочет. И DDMS распознает его кучей вопросиков.

Comment: Приложения - Разработка - Отладка USB галочка стоит?

Comment: Да, стоит.

Comment: В общем, порылся по инету и нашел вот это: http://www.mjonik.pl/blog/2010/01/samsung-galaxy-with-android-sdk-on-ubuntu/
Помогло

Answer (score 2):

Перед тем как писать в `Bundle` устройства, надо проверить значение `BluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()` если `false` надо записать в `Bundle` нечто вроде `saveInstanceState.putBoolean("btEnabled", false)` и не писать больше ничего. Далее при извлечении в `onActivityCreated()` проверить значение ключа `btEnabled` и действовать сообразно обстановке.

P.S. А вообще почему действительно не пользуетесь отладчиком прямо на самом девайсе? Надо декларировать в манифесте, что будете отлаживать и вперед.

Comment: Про манифест можно поподробнее?

Comment: @Barmaley, кстати, проверить, включен ли БТ можно непосредственно здесь:
if (savedInstanceState == null || !mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {}
Однако, хотелось бы, чтобы те девайсы, которые были найдены отображались постоянно, и, если пользователь решил выключить БТ, то при попытке соединиться с удаленным устройством происходил запрос на включение БТ.

Comment: @RomanoO касательно флага отладки - смотрите сюда http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#debug